# Google HTTP Load Balancer Unable to Upgrade Web Socket Connection

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've just added an HTTP Load Balancer pointing to a couple of Google Compute Engine instances running Tornado web servers. In particular, they are handling websockets.

When I visit a page with an embedded websocket through the load balancer (in Chrome) I get:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

This is through DNS as well as hitting the load balancer's IP.

However, when I hit an individual instance, I am able to succesfully handshake a websocket.

When I get the page via the load balancer, I'm not seeing any 400 logs in the webserver, further indicating that it's the load balancer that isn't letting it through.

Is there something I can do to allow the HTTP 'Upgrade'? Or is this not possible in the Cloud Platform HTTP Load Balancer.

EDIT: I can also handshake the websocket through a 'Network Load Balancer', so all signs point to the HTTP Load Balancer being the issue.

Answer (score 5):

As of today (July 2015), GCP's HTTP LB and AWS's ELB do not support Websockets.

The workaround for GCP is to use the Network Load Balancer (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/).

The workaround for ELB is to use TCP/SSL instead of HTTP/HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up the load balancer to use TCP or SSL rather than HTTP or HTTPS.   I was having the same problem on AWS load balancer and that switch seemed to solve the problem.  I suspect that the HTTP setting is filtering some packets which the websocket needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is now resolved (as of 2017)
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_proxy_support
Should require no changes on your end to utilize.

Comment: Google's *External Load Balancer* supports Web sockets, but Internal HTTP Load Balancers do not support web sockets (which is very weird).

Comment: indeed, however this doesn't work always with some services like Atlantis. See: https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/issues/2542#issuecomment-1952451573

Answer (score 0):

Are you instances showing healthy in the LB? If this is the case, you can do a tcpdump to see how your instance is replying behind the LB and directly. Make sure the response behind the LB's IP is coming from you instance's public IP and not the private IP.

If it's unhealthy, then you need to double check the instances and make sure the TCP connection closes properly every time.